# Could not initialize Applet Error

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, java-3d

I have installed java version 1.7 on my ubuntu pc . I have latest iced tea web plugin installed on my firefox . I have installed java3d 1.5.2 api . I have set paths for both java and java-3d . Still when I click http://ccnsb06-iiith.vlabs.ac.in/exp2/ve_exp2.html which has an applet runs based on java 3d api,
it is giving an error

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B41p1ExqjUEOM3hjdUNwNjBldXc/view?usp=sharing

P.S : I have same problem with my CentOs 6 machine

Comment: It doesn't find the class "MyApplet", the initialization fails. The Java applets are a bit broken because of numerous security changes since Java 1.6 update 10, I advise you to redeploy it elsewhere with Java3D 1.6.0 instead of Java3D 1.5.2.

Comment: Even the problem is same for java3d -1.6.0

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Maybe the class MyApplet is really missing.

Comment: I've just checked, the class file is missing from this webpage, it doesn't find iiit.vlabdemos.epr.epr$MyApplet. The attribute "archive" doesn't appear in the HTML code, I don't see where the JAR is.

Comment: Thanks for your insight , Can you tell how to modify HTML code so as to include JAR files or the attribute "archive" ?

Comment: I don't know where the expected JAR file containing the missing class is located. Moreover, if it isn't self contained, you'll have to deploy the dependencies too, i.e Java3D 1.6 + JOGL 2. The "archive" attribute of the "applet" tag should contain a list of the required JARs separated by commas, for example: "your_jar.jar,j3dcore.jar,j3dutils.jar,vecmath.jar,gluegen-rt.jar,jogl-all.jar" (of course, replace "your_jar" by the real name of your own JAR). You should use the JARs listed here: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#download